# Python WebScraping for redirecting URL (SAML authentication)

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am doing Python web scraping. For a single page authentication, I am able to do but my page on which I have to do Python webscraping redirects to a SAML authentication page.

```
import requests

User = 'abcd'
Pass = 'abcd'

payload = {
    'UserName': User,
    'Password': Pass
}

session = requests.session()

moodle_url = "http://orginalpage.com/"
response = session.get(moodle_url)
print(response)
cookies = session.cookies.get_dict()
print(cookies)


SAML_url = response.url
response = session.post(SAML_url, payload)

with requests.Session() as session:
    post = session.post('https://saml.redirected.page.com', data=payload)
    r = session.get('http://saml.page.com')
    print(r.text)
```

When i run this, this is giving  me nothing. How can i enable login on SAML page and redirect back to original page for scraping.

Thanks.

Comment: You will have to use python plugin Selenium. It will allow you to input username and password as well as selecting the return button. If you would like some help please post more information like the HTML and so on. https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html follow this link here for more information

Comment: It's also possible to login using requests but you need to inspect the exact POST the site makes when doing so. Probably you also need to extract a crsf-token on the login-page and use this in your payload/header. Without the exact site it's hard to say what is needed. It's very much site dependant...

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it with cURL commands. This doesn't require selenium or any third party libraries.

1. Open the developer tools in your browser and click the network tab
2. Navigate to your website and log in manually
3. You will see the session with the url as 'host'
4. Right-click the session (the first session after logging in) and copy the cURL address.
   [image]

5. Open a cURL converter website such as https://curlconverter.com/
6. paste your cURL and copy the converted python code
7. paste the code in your python code and use the cookies and headers, meaning

```
response = requests.get('https://your-url.com', cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
```

`response.content` is the site you're looking for.